# Is there any way to have Apache / PHP log specifically why a 500 is being returned?

Tags: php, apache, logging, error-handling

I understand a 500 response can be returned under a variety of different scenarios, but is there any way to have the server log *specifically* what caused the 500? Or for that matter print it to the PHP page/output?

**EDIT:**

I'm on MediaTemple's Grid Service, display errors is on in `phpinfo()`, the following is in my PHP code:  `ini_set('display_errors',1);` `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);`

and error logging is turned on in my hosting configuration, yet when I `tail` the log, nothing appears when I hit refresh. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're generating the 500 yourself, then use error_log() to save the reason into PHP's own error log. Apache itself won't generally know anything about PHP's internal state. If PHP is crashing and Apache's logging the 500, then it'll have a few details about the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the 500 error should be in Apache's error log already.  If PHP was responsible, then the error will be shown on screen if you have `display_errors = On`  in php.ini.

Comment: I have error logging turned on in PHP and in the hosting configuration yet each time I generate a 500 nothing is written to the log. That, and no error message is being printed to the page other than the usual 'Internal Server Error'. If I don't see it in the log I have, don't have access to Apache's core logs (due to my provider), and can't print it to the screen, is there any way else to see the specific reason for the error?

Comment: Does the PHP error log you're looking at usually get error output written to it? Can you deliberately write to it using `error_log('put this in the error log')`? If not, then the problem is that your PHP error log isn't being used at all. Get that fixed, and the errors that generate your 500 errors should show up there as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$log_file = 'c:temp\test_error.txt';
register_shutdown_function('handleShutdown');

function handleShutdown() {
    global $log_file;
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error !== NULL) {
        $info = "[SHUTDOWN] file:" . $error['file'] . " | ln:" . $error['line'] . " | msg:" . $error['message'] . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents($log_file, $info, FILE_APPEND);
    } else {
        file_put_contents($log_file, "SHUTDOWN ", FILE_APPEND);
    }
}
```